# Problems with #define - expected expression before "=" token

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, c-preprocessor

Beginner's question: I dared to introduce constants into my little program. I first resisted, but then I thought I should give it a try... to see that it doesn't work.

Okay, this is what I have put in the very first line of my .m file:

```
#define kPageCurlSpeed = 2.5;
```

And this is what I put in my method:

```
[UIView setAnimationDuration:kPageCurlSpeed];
```

And behold... it doesn't work and I get the compiler message that "expected expression before "=" token"... I have no idea of how to translate that into English.

I thought the compiler simply replaces kPageCurlSpeed with 2.5 -- so this shouldn't cause any problems. But I guess that's just theory.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You don't need `=` in an `#define` or the semicolon afterwards. Just use

```
#define kPageCurlSpeed  2.5
```

Read e.g. [this wikipedia article on C preprocessor.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor)