# Error:expected expression before '=' token

Tags: objective-c

I am getting an error as expected expression before '=' token.

```
#define RMH_MAX_UNENCODED_LENGTH= (RMH_MESSAGE_MAX_SIZE - RMH_ENCODED_MSG_OVERHEAD); // RMH_MAX_UNENCODED_LENGTH =4064

#define RMH_MAX_ENCODED_LENGTH = (3*sizeof(RMH_MAX_UNENCODED_LENGTH) / 4);//RMH_MAX_ENCODED_LENGTH =4;

int k = RMH_MAX_UNENCODED_LENGTH; //Error:expected expression before '=' token
NSLog(@"f:%d",k);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [problems with #define - expected expression before "=" token](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5516442/problems-with-define-expected-expression-before-token)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong. Use:

```
#define RMH_MAX_UNENCODED_LENGTH (RMH_MESSAGE_MAX_SIZE - RMH_ENCODED_MSG_OVERHEAD)
```

Note: no `=`, no `;`, no comment after it.

`define`s are "simply" pure text substitutions.

Answer (score 4):

You don't want an "=" or a ";" in those #define statements.  The syntax is...

```
#define symbol value
```

It's a good idea to put parentheses as you've done.

This is just plain C, no "Ojbective" stuff here.  You might want to pick up a book on C to learn things like this.